# Boot Windows from Shell Script in Linux, Without Waiting for Grub Timeout

Tags: shell-script, arch-linux, grub

I want to write a shell script to boot into windows without waiting the normal grub timeout.
The command mustn't change grub-timeout from its default value, as I still want to choose Linux or Windows next boot.
Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo grub-reboot 2
# set timeout 0 temporarily
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For any future readers, here's the solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo efibootmgr -n [x]
sudo reboot
```

Where [x] is the index of your Windows Boot Manager (usually 0), which you can find by running

```
efibootmgr -d -d
```

Unfortunately it would seem sudo is required to set next boot, so even if you set an alias or function in your .zshenv or .bash_profile, you'll still have to enter your password.

Thanks to @MarcusMüller for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to post your solution. You can also [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) (after 48 hours so other peple can have a chance to answer as well).

Comment: You can always add a line to sudoers or pack it in a setuid-script to avoid the need for providing the password...